# How can I add multiple onclick options on a div by using and if php statement?

Tags: php, html

I was thinking something like this would work, but it just uses the ('flipped') option regardless of the `$comp_iteam` variable.

```
    <div class="flipper" id="kat"  onclick= " <?php

    if ($comp_iteam = 'heads') {  
        echo "this.classList.toggle('flipped')";
    } else {
        echo "this.classList.toggle('flippes')";
    }

   ?>">
```

Comment: In your `if` condition, you're using `=`, thats assigning a variable. Instead, you need to use `==` or `===` for comparison.

Comment: @CodeGodie that's right he is not do assignment instead of comparison

Answer (score 0):

your code does not have correct syntax

you must replace

```
  if ($comp_iteam = 'heads') {
```

with

```
 if ($comp_iteam == 'heads') {
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that just makes it so that neither of the onclick options work. Any other ideas?

Comment: you must show full code so that we can understand why this thing is used`  echo "this.classList.toggle('flippes')";`

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div class="flipper" id="kat"  onclick= " <?php

    if ($comp_iteam == 'heads') {  
        echo "this.classList.toggle('flipped')";
    } else {
        echo "this.classList.toggle('flippes')";
    }

?>">
```

whenever you assignig some value for variable you should use '=='

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that just makes it so that neither of the onclick options work. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick= "<?php echo ($comp_iteam == 'heads') ? "this.classList.toggle('flipped')" : "this.classList.toggle('flippes')";?>"
```

I dont know whether its right or wrong please try this too bro

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="flipper" id="kat"  onclick= " <?php

    if ($comp_iteam == 'heads') {  
        echo "this.classList.toggle('flipped')"; } else {
        echo "this.classList.toggle('flippes')";}

?>">
```